# Encoding video with gst from local file to local file

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I have a local uncompressed .avi file, and I want to encode it.
I tried to do so from the bash:

```
"gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=path/to/file.avi ~ video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1, format=I420 ! nv_omx_h264enc quality-level=2 ! mp4mux ! filesink location= path/test.mp4"
```

or switch the 'mp4mux' with 'qtmux'.

It didn't work, and the debugging output is "erroneous pipeline: could not link filesrc0 to omxh264enc0"

I would like for some help and some explanation about the syntax and how this thing works haha!
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried the built-in ffmpeg command - not sure what distro you're using but on Raspbian Jessie it comes with it renamed as "avconv". Typically a one line command will get you started before using options - something like: `avconv -i input.avi -strict -2 output.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline doesn't seem right. Try this instead:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=path/to/file.avi caps="video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1, format=I420" ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=15000000 control-rate=variable ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,profile=high ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=path/test.mp4
```

you might need to tweak the bitrate, control rate etc to get the desired results but this gives you a place to start.